# Is there any way to calculate the Average without the tables having columns in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table 'Score' it contains all the created measures in my Power Bi. I'm having trouble getting the right Average of fill rate per Employee Name in my matrix.

This is the value of Fill Rate

Fill Rate = [Ratings]*[Weight] + 0

This is what I've tried:

Average_FR_Score =
DIVIDE (
SUMX (
VALUES ( Score ),
[Ratings] * [Weight] + 0
),
COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( Score ) )
)

but I'm getting an error: **Table 'Score' cannot be used in computations because it does not have any columns.****

How can I get the average of the overall fill rate of Employees?